# Select ALL rows where Pandas DataFrame Column values in a List

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am working with this problems for hours and i just couldn't get the right result.

I have a DataFrame that looks like this:

```
df:
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
aaa  bbb  ccc  1
aaa  bbb  ccc  2
aaa  bbb  ccc  3
aaa  bbb  ccc  4
aaa  bbb  ccc  5
```

And a List = [1,3,5]

What I want to do is to select all rows in df where the Col4 values in the List.

I want the result to be:

```
new_df:
Col1 Col2 Col3 Col4
aaa  bbb  ccc  1
aaa  bbb  ccc  3
aaa  bbb  ccc  5
```

My code looks like this:

```
new_df = df[df['Col4'].isin(List)]
```

My Output/Error is:

```
Empty DataFrame
Columns: [Col1, Col2, Col3, Col4]
Index: []

[0 rows x 4 columns]
```

Im very new to python3 and Pandas. Any help and hints are appriciated. Thanks is advance...

Comment: it col4 ofc. typo... sorry

Comment: The dtype for Col4 is likely an int or float, whereas your list is likely stored as a string. This may be why you are not getting any results back, as the code appears to be correct.

Comment: i explicitly convert the List values to int()... how can i convert the df['Col4'] to int? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since it isn't clear what the `dtype` is (I highly suspect it is a dtype of integers), then you can just use [`pd.Series.infer_dtypes`](https://pandas-docs.github.io/pandas-docs-travis/generated/pandas.DataFrame.infer_objects.html) (new in `v0.22`) and filter on the result.

```
m = df.Col4.infer_objects().isin([1, 3, 5])
m

0     True
1    False
2     True
3    False
4     True
Name: Col4, dtype: bool
```

```
df[m]

  Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4
0  aaa  bbb  ccc     1
2  aaa  bbb  ccc     3
4  aaa  bbb  ccc     5
```

---

If you want to stick to the old fashioned way of doing it, there's always `astype`.

```
df[df.Col4.astype(int).isin([1, 3, 5])]
```

Or, if that doesn't work, use `to_numeric`;

```
df[pd.to_numeric(df.Col4, errors='coerce').isin([1, 3, 5])]

  Col1 Col2 Col3  Col4
0  aaa  bbb  ccc     1
2  aaa  bbb  ccc     3
4  aaa  bbb  ccc     5
```